# Select one Checkbox When All chekboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I am looking for the logic where I have the list of some data in while loop fetched using php just as below.

```
  if (mysql_num_rows($results) != 0) {
      // displaying records.
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
          echo '<div id="checkboxlist">';
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="'.$row['Id'].'" id="Checkbox1"></td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['phone'].'</th>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['fax'].'</td>';
          echo '<td><button><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['Id'].'">Edit</a></button></td>';
          echo '<td><a onclick="return deleteRec();" href="ajax_delete.php?id='.$row['Id'].'" id="deleteOne">Delete</a></td>';
          echo '<td><a href="view.php?id='.$row['Id'].'" target="_blank">View</a></td>';

          echo '</div>';
      }
  } else {
      echo '<td colspan="9"><h1>No contacts found.</td></h1>';
  }
```

Now As we have more than one checkbox if multiple data are retrieved , I have one more checkbox,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>              
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll"/>
        </td>
        <td colspan="8" align="right">
            <button type="submit" onClick="return massDelete()" name="delete" class="delete" disabled>Delete All</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am confused that , if I select all the data retrieved checkboxes , the lone check box should automatically selected, i.e If 5 datas are selected out of 10 retrieved, that the checkbox with `id="checkAll"` should not be selected. Instead if I select all the 10 checkbox, only than that particular checkbox with `id="checkAll"` should be selected.

Comment: Try this: `$('.checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if ($('.checkbox1:checked').length === $('.checkbox1').length) {
    $('#checkAll').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
` And to make all checkboxes checked after clicking _check all_ use `$('#checkAll').on('change', function() {
  $('.checkbox1').prop('checked', this.checked);
});`

Comment: @RayonDabre Make it an answer...

Comment: the second part of checking/unchecking all the checkboxes have been done perfectly. That works. But the first part remains. Thank you for the efforts sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen `change` event of the `checkboxes` and if `length` of `checked` checkboxes matches with the `length` of the checkboxes having class `checkbox1` then `check` the `check all` checkbox.

Try this:

```js
$('.checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  var bool = $('.checkbox1:checked').length === $('.checkbox1').length;
  $('#checkAll').prop('checked', bool);
});

$('#checkAll').on('change', function() {
  $('.checkbox1').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll" />Check all
<br>
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="">
<br>
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="">
<br>
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="">
<br>
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="">
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0a7jfvma/1/)